# Redirecting Output of Bash Child Scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have a basic script that outputs various status messages. e.g.

```
~$ ./myscript.sh
0 of 100
1 of 100
2 of 100
...
```

I wanted to wrap this in a parent script, in order to run a sequence of child-scripts and send an email upon overall completion, e.g. topscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
START=$(date +%s)
/usr/local/bin/myscript.sh
/usr/local/bin/otherscript.sh
/usr/local/bin/anotherscript.sh
RET=$?
END=$(date +%s)
echo -e "Subject:Task Complete\nBegan on $START and finished at $END and exited with status $RET.\n" | sendmail -v group@mydomain.com
```

I'm running this like:

```
~$ topscript.sh >/var/log/topscript.log 2>&1
```

However, when I run `tail -f /var/log/topscript.log` to inspect the log I see nothing, even though running top shows myscript.sh is currently being executed, and therefore, presumably outputting status messages.

Why isn't the stdout/stderr from the child scripts being captured in the parent's log?  How do I fix this?

EDIT: I'm also running these on a remote machine, connected via ssh using pseudo-tty allocation, e.g. `ssh -t user@host`. Could the pseudo-tty be interfering?

Comment: If shelter's answer below doesn't help, you might want to try narrowing down where this is going wrong. Some things to try: (1) Does `./myscript.sh >tmp.log 2>&1` write to `tmp.log`? If not, maybe it's checking `[[ -t 1 ]]` and only writing messages when standard output is a TTY. (2) After `topscript.sh` completes, do you see messages in the log? (In other words, is it just that they're delayed? This is what shelter and onlyone's answers are both suggesting.)

Answer (score 2):

I just tried your the following: I have three files t1.sh, t2.sh, and t3.sh all with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

for((i=0;i<10;i++)) ; do
    echo $i of 9
    sleep 1
done
```

And a script called myscript.sh with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash

./t1.sh
./t2.sh
./t3.sh

echo "All Done"
```

When I run `./myscript.sh > topscript.log 2>&1` and then in another terminal run `tail -f topscript.log` I see the lines being output just fine in the log file.

Perhaps the things being run in your subscripts use a large output buffer? I know when I've run python scripts before, it has a pretty big output buffer so you don't see any output for a while. Do you actually see the entire output in the email that gets sent out at the end of topscript.sh? Is it just that while the processes run you're not seeing the output?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
unbuffer topscript.sh >/var/log/topscript.log 2>&1
```

Note that unbuffer is not always available as a std binary in old-style Unix platforms and may require a search and installation for a package to support it.

I hope this helps.